# How to put focus inside a div which is having same class with a value true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dojo

inputs id are generated dynamically and changed with every build

```
<div class="red"> <input id="a"  value="false" />test</div>
<div class="red"> <input id="b"  value="false" />test</div>
<div class="red"> <input id="c"  value="false" />test</div>
<div class="red"> <input id="d"  value="true" />test successful</div>
```

i need to put focus on last input box because its having value true

Comment: var idArray = [];
$('.red').each(function () {
    idArray.push(this.id);
});

Comment: this im trying but how to proceed further? dnt kwn ?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you are currently using. And please, try to write an understandable english for all.

Answer (score 1):

> How to get value of all input box inside div which is having same class

```
 $('.red input');
```

> put focus input whose value is true

```
 $('.red input[value=true]').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set focus on the last element using JQuery like so:

```
$("div.red").last().find("input").focus();
```

[Have a look at this example code](https://jsfiddle.net/f7rsbrp6/)